# Spring Boot aplication shuts down after running for some time

Tags: spring-boot, shutdown

I have spring boot application with oauth2 security mySql database connection and some controllers. I have deployed it on AWS server it works fine but it shuts down after a while it does not get many API calls so no reason for DDOS fail or outOfMemmory errors I can see in logs the following message

> 2018-10-28 10:58:55.979  INFO 1253 --- [       Thread-3] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3ac42916: startup date [Sun Oct 28 08:46:01 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
>   2018-10-28 10:58:55.983  INFO 1253 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
>   2018-10-28 10:58:55.985  INFO 1253 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
>   2018-10-28 10:58:55.986  INFO 1253 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
>   2018-10-28 10:58:55.993  INFO 1253 --- [       Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>   2018-10-28 10:58:55.994  INFO 1253 --- [       Thread-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
>   2018-10-28 10:58:56.002  INFO 1253 --- [       Thread-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Here is my pom.xml

> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>       4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>core</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>core</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my application.properies

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.username = xxx
spring.datasource.password = xxx
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

logging.path=logs/core/

Comment: Does it persist on your local machine or only on AWS?

Comment: So far it looks like it only happens on AWS, locally it looks fine

Comment: Have you configured properly the datasource url to AWS RDS? Cuz in your paste it looks like it still looking for localhost. And look to security policies too.

Comment: Yes I changed the db connection url

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for those that may have similar problem I discovered that running procces using screen mode in linux fixes the problem